# Is GNOME-DO Themeable?

Tags: themes, customization, gnome-do

I was wondering if Gnome DO is themable, besides the 5 pre-installed themes.. I took a look at the projects' page and didn't discover anything. Do you know if there is any chance of unofficial theming or theming plugins? Have anyone tried to change the source code in order to change the theme?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's entirely possible to add themes to Do, but it does require coding, although it's pretty simple.  It'd be technically feasible to write a theme which loaded SVGs, which could then provide easily-installable themes.

I'm not particularly interested in doing that in the immediate future - I find the existing themes sufficient, and there are problems I'm more interested in fixing - but I'd be happy to review a merge request.  To do that, you'd make a branch of [Do's source code](https://code.launchpad.net/do), make your changes, push that branch up to launchpad, and then request a merge into trunk with `bzr lp-propose lp:do`.

You're welcome to hop on to `#gnome-do` on freenode, too.  It's fairly quiet, so if you ask a question don't be surprised if it takes a while for someone to get back to you :).

Do's not dead - I've made two releases this year already, and have some core enhancements nearly ready to merge.

Comment: *Do* is still, imo, a great improvement on many things that came after it.

Comment: When doing that kind of edit to someone's answer, make a comment first.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, GNOME Do can be user themed, but you will probably not find any themes floating around, or any documentation, because GNOME Do has been replaced (for several months now) by [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project)* and [Docky](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki), both of which can be themed.

*See also this [wiki](http://synapse.zeitgeist-project.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page).

> *From by GNOME Do's maintainer: Do's not dead :).  Synapse is a fine project, but I (obviously!) think that there's still stuff Do does better.*